# How to get manipulation events work on the UIElement placed inside the Scroll viewer

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, scrollviewer, user-interaction

I have UIelement placed inside the scroll viewer. At one case, I want to disable the manipulation event of scroll viewer and enable the manipulation event of UIElement by using ManipulationMode and CancelDirectManipulation() of scroll viewer as like,

```
Protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    scrollViewer.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.System;
     scrollViewer.DirectManipulationStarted += ScrollContent_DirectManipulationStarted;
    imageryLayer.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.System; // UIElement placed inside the
                                                                                                                         //scroll viewer
}

private void ScrollContent_DirectManipulationStarted(object sender, object e)
        {        
            this.scrollContent.CancelDirectManipulations();

        }
```

After doing like this, only pointer events of the control get fired and not its manipulation events. Could anyone share is it possible to fire the manipulation events of the UIElement placed inside the scroll viewer?

Answer (score 0):

After you cancel [Direct Manipulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446969(v=vs.85).aspx) processing at the start of a `ScrollViewer` interaction, you could custom input handling.  But the `ManipulationModes.System` you set for the `UIElement` is for enable system-driven touch interactions supported through Direct Manipulation. If you want the [UIElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielemen)  to support manipulation events such as `ManipulationStarted`,`ManipulationDelta`,you must set the `ManipulationMode` to a value other than `System` or `None`. So that please try to change the `ManipulationMode` for the inside `UIElement`.

```
imageryLayer.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
```

More details please reference [Quickstart: Touch input (XAML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh465387(v=win.10)).